# Multiple EXISTS statements make query exponentially slow

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a query with multiple `EXISTS` statements and I don't understand why it becomes exponentially slow after about 7 `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT `products`.`id`
FROM `products`
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #1 ~30ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #2 ~30ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #3 ~30ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #4 ~35ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #5 ~35ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #6 ~35ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #7 ~40ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #8 ~100ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #9 ~500ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #10 ~4800ms
  AND EXISTS(SELECT `vehicles`.`id` FROM `vehicles`) #11 ~52500ms
```

As you can see, the first 7th `EXISTS` are pretty fast... then the performance goes down very quickly.

`products` and `vehicles` are pretty simple tables, with 1000 and 5000 rows respectively.

Here is the explain statement:

```
+--+-----------+--------+----------+-----+-------------+-------+-------+----+----+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table   |partitions|type |possible_keys|key    |key_len|ref |rows|filtered|Extra                                                           |
+--+-----------+--------+----------+-----+-------------+-------+-------+----+----+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch                                         |
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |vehicles|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|5266|100     |Using index; FirstMatch(vehicles); Using join buffer (hash join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |products|NULL      |index|NULL         |PRIMARY|8      |NULL|959 |100     |Using index; Using join buffer (hash join)                      |
+--+-----------+--------+----------+-----+-------------+-------+-------+----+----+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And the table definitions:

```
Products:
+-----+---------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|Field|Type           |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
+-----+---------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|id   |bigint unsigned|NO  |PRI|NULL   |auto_increment|
|name |varchar(255)   |NO  |   |NULL   |              |
+-----+---------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
```

```
Vehicles:
+-----+---------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|Field|Type           |Null|Key|Default|Extra         |
+-----+---------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
|id   |bigint unsigned|NO  |PRI|NULL   |auto_increment|
|name |varchar(255)   |NO  |   |NULL   |              |
+-----+---------------+----+---+-------+--------------+
```

The MySQL version is 8.0.23.

This is a working fiddle reproducing the problem https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0d671779e1a8335dd585508cc657429

I know this query doesn't make any sense but it is a strange behavior I only observe in MySQL 8.0 (in the fiddle you can switch the MySQL version to < 8.0, or use MariaDB, and the performances will be ok).

This is all about curiosity, understanding why it behaves like this, with this particular query.

Do you have any idea about what can cause this ?

Comment: Show us the actual subqueries, not a simplified version, and the table definitions including indexes.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I removed the misleading part were I stated it was simplified, you can forget about it, that's the actuel query. I have also edited my question to include the explain statement and table definitions.

Comment: Optimizer tried to find the best plan for query and each subselect adds a new dimension to the search space. Try to wrap your query into `SET profiling=1;
/* your query here */
SHOW PROFILE;
SET profiling=0;`

Comment: I know this is just a demo, but usually you would be filtering inside those subqueries - currently you'll be returning every row in Product if there are any rows in Vehicle (no matter if they match on Id or not). The performance problem for this is that it has decided to start by going through each of the subqueries first to check they return rows - presumably it's forgetting it only needs to find 1 row before moving on to the next table and is joining them together (and there's no filters between them so it's just a cross join), potentially it's doing this on just the first 100 rows it sees.

Comment: The query as stated doesn't make the slightest bit of sense, because the subqueries have no correlation to the outer query, so this is simply not a realistic scenario. Try to produce a [mcve] that we can work with.

Comment: Consider REMOVING the quote marks where your have 'id' to simply be id - to avoid DATATYPE confusion/manipulation.  BIGINT columns do not need quotes since they are expected to be numerical values, always.

Comment: I've done some digging into the hash joins. Behaviour was introduced in 8.0.18 to force MySQL to use hash joins whenever possible (a questionable considering MySQL hasn't had hash joins for very long so SQL is not going to be written to be optimized for that) and since 8.0.19 the only way to disable this is with hints (although I'm struggling to achieve this) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hash-joins.html . If the subqueries were correlated, the plan would be much more favourable (and the query would make sense).

Comment: I've put together a minimal reproducible example for you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f9b66665caed4e2b0e88622dcc1ffbe you can switch the MySQL version to see a plan which doesn't use Hash Joins. 8.0 here is 8.0.26 and the explain analyze tells us that only one row is used for each of the hash joins (so it doesn't suffer from the exponential performance degrade) - how does that compare to your 8.0.23 version?

Comment: What happens when you have an index (or PK) on `vehicles.id`?

Comment: @AndrewSayer Thank you for the fiddle. The explain analyze produces the same output on my side with 8.0.23. It is worth noting the performance degradation is also present on the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0d671779e1a8335dd585508cc657429, only for MySQL 8.0 (if you switch to MariaDB or MySQL < 8.0, it works fine). To answer the comments about the lack of sense of these queries, after some digging on an unrelated problem, I found this strange behavior. I understand this is not realistic but that's not really the point here. It's just curiosity, understanding "why".

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please put a working fiddle into the question - your query as is makes no sense! Also, please put any (other) relevant back into the question also - having to trawl through comments is a source of cognitive dissonance and quite possibly may discourage some users from answering - help us to help you!

Comment: @Vérace I've updated the question to include most of my previous comment in the question, including the fiddle. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: If out of curiosity you want to know *why* this is slow, it's because the query plan generated involves 11 hash joins. This is likely because of the nonsensical use of the `EXISTS` clause to select **all** vehicles, 11 times over.  `EXISTS` is a useful clause in certain situations, but most times you should stick to a more relational solution that involves joins. But the bigger issue here is the redundancy of selecting all rows 11 times over, which produced a less than optimal query plan. Basically it's like sticking your hand in fire and asking "*why does it hurt?*"...because fire is hot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of the remark _ I understand this is not realistic but that's not really the point here. It's just curiosity, understanding "why"._ and the off chance that only the developers of MySQL 8.0.x will be able to address the issue.